# Bash - Sed with square brackets

Tags: bash, file, sed, backslash, square-bracket

is exist any solution to use this sed (sed have problems with [ ] symbols):

```
sed -i "s|$old|$new|" $pathtofile
```

When i have in file on specific line string with "[]", for example:

```
something1 = [value]
```

In $old variable i have this line. Maybe some kind of reading variable and adding backslash before every [ or ] symbol? It is possible? Or is there better way to do it. I need to change line in file.

Comment: Please post more accurate samples of input and expected output as it is not clear from here.

Comment: I want to change $old="something1 = [value]" to  $new="something1 = [helloworld]", for example. Input with some square brackets and output have some too. But output and input is in string variable already.

Comment: Not clear please post more samples in your POST in CODE TAGS and let me know then.